# Python: Process/Thread Monitoring

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, monitoring, process

Currently i can list my processes with a simple python script:

import os
os.system("Tasklist")

I would like to list all the threads associated with those processes, if any. The count of threads per process might be sufficient.

Would someone direct me where i might find this information.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [**psutil**](http://code.google.com/p/psutil) module [(download here)](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/downloads/list) for cross-platform process information delivery.

After installing, use the following code to get the thread count of any process id.

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print proc.name+' ['+str(proc.get_num_threads())+' threads]'
```

Comment: so for more depth i am guessing i should learn about psutil. would that be correct?

Comment: @JeffUnderwood `os.system("Tasklist")` would only be able to work under Windows-based platforms, but psutil is cross-platform and can work on many other systems. They say that "it [psutil] currently supports **Linux**, **Windows**, **OSX**, and **FreeBSD**, both **32-bit** and **64-bit**, with Python versions from **2.4** to **3.3** by using a single code base." It has pretty straightforward documentation at http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation